# How to give the two font background color in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

My text box contain the following data

```
head
this is the heading

paragraph1
this is the paragraph1

paragraph2
this is the paragraph2

-----END-------

head
this is the heading

paragraph1
this is the paragragrph1

paragraph2
this is the paragragrph2

paragraph3
this is the paragragrph3
```

I'm trying to add the red as a background color for `head` and green for `paragraph`, so I tried as following

```
line_number = 1
match_color = 0
for Z in (etc_data):
    if(re.match("head",Z)):
        str_len = len(Z)
        output_txtbox.tag_add("start", "%d.0"%(line_number), "%d.%s"%(line_number,str_len))
        output_txtbox.tag_config("start", background="red", foreground="white")
        match_color = 0
    if(re.match("paragraph",Z)):
        print "HI";
        str_len = len(Z)
        output_txtbox.tag_add("start", "%d.0"%(line_number), "%d.%s"%(line_number,str_len))     
        output_txtbox.tag_config("start", background="green", foreground="white")           
    line_number += 1
    match_color+=1
```

But the problem is both are showing the `red color`. I don't know what is the problem. How can I fix it?

Comment: You're giving both of your colorized regions the same tag name - so they're actually the same region.  Give them different names, move the ``tag_config`` outside of the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is because you have two times the same tag: `start`. You could try:

```py
line_number = 1
match_color = 0  
for Z in (etc_data):
    if(re.match("head",Z)):
        str_len = len(Z)
        output_txtbox.tag_add("tag_head", "%d.0"%(line_number), "%d.%s"%    (line_number,str_len))

        match_color = 0
    if(re.match("paragraph",Z)):
        print "HI";
        str_len = len(Z)
        output_txtbox.tag_add("tag_paragraph", "%d.0"%(line_number), "%d.%s"%    (line_number,str_len))     

    line_number += 1
    match_color+=1             

# Configuring tags
output_txtbox.tag_config("tag_head", background="red",     foreground="white")
output_txtbox.tag_config("tag_paragraph", background="green",     foreground="white")
```